# Ubuntu 18.04.3 64bits not booting after restart

Tags: boot, 18.04, apt, updates, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Legion Y540-17IRH-PG0 and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 64 bits, and the following problem started happening last week:

After installing Visual Studio Code and sudo apt-get update/sudo apt-get upgrade, I got a message from Software Updater telling me I should restart my laptop in order to finish some software updates. After restarting it, the boot failed and I got [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVYZr.jpg). I tried reinstalling Ubuntu multiple times, but everytime I restart my computer after a apt-get update/apt-get upgrade, I get this screen and I have to start the process all over again.

What should I do? Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Do you see the GRUB menu when you boot the computer? If so, enter "e" for edit mode, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x to continue booting. If you can boot, check that you've got the latest Nvidia driver installed.

Comment: I don't see it. When I try booting the computer, I get the 'Legion' screen, then it goes away, as it usually did for regular bootings, but then it goes back to the 'Legion' screen again and I get that black screen with the colorful line.

Comment: Next try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and tell me what happens.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, does Windows operate normally?

Comment: Not a dual-boot, solely Ubuntu. And I managed to get to the GRUB menu, did as you said and managed to normally boot!

Comment: How do I find about the Nvidia drivers? And how do I know I have the latest ones installed?

Comment: Now do these commands... `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `dpkg -l *nvidia*` and `uname -r`.

Comment: I got these [results](https://imgur.com/a/3TTh2xp)

Comment: I have some answers for you... but I have to leave for a bit... when I come back I'll write an answer for you, and notify you when I'm done... ok?

Comment: Okay, no worries! Thank you very much for the help so far.

Comment: I've put together an initial answer for you...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hello, heynemma. Had a busy day yesterday, just found the time to go back to it. I'll update you soon.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hello heynnema.

Finally managed to find out a solution. Apparently, [blacklisting the Nouveau drivers on GRUB](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) was a solution for my problem. I did it yesterday at evening and been testing it since then, and so far it's working properly, and I can manage to shut down/restart any time. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: It's not clear why that solved the problem. If you were running with the Nvidia driver, the nouveau driver is not used. The only other issue is the version of the Nvidia driver that you were using, hence that part of my answer. Please keep me posted if you have future problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's are the updates for your Nvidia video card, and your BIOS.

**NVIDIA:**

Install version 430.09 of their driver.

https://www.geforce.com/drivers

[image]

**BIOS:**

You have BIOS version BHCN21WW. Current is BHCN35WW.

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y540-17irh-pg0/downloads/ds539700

**Note**: Backup your important data before a BIOS update.

**Note**: Lenovo may be able to update itself from within the current BIOS

**Note**: Watch this video on how to do this without Windows... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDUCfU-e-A

[image]

Comment: Tried to do that, also didn't work out. And I got some [errors](https://imgur.com/a/EOo6Ddl) as I tried to boot again -

Comment: @manticorevault Did you power off, then on, and then boot? Did you note what custom settings you have, then try to reset the BIOS to system defaults? In the new BIOS, can you disable TPM? If you've done all that, I'd call/contact Lenovo support. Did you already do the Nvidia driver? Does the computer still boot?

Comment: I already updated the NVidia driver, yes. And still the same problem. I'll check if I can reset the BIOS.